# Как при помощи js менять параметры в url?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть затруднения с js (только его изучаю). Есть интернет-магазин, в его каталоге есть возможность фильтрации товаров (по цвету/материалу/производителю и т.д). Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при изменении параметров фильтрации в каталоге клиентом, его перекидывало на 1 страницу каталога. Как это можно сделать?
Ссылки формируются следующим образом:

mysite.ru/product-category/kriuchki/?search=&price_min=0&price_max=1051&page=5&sort=-count_showing&card_type=tile

Нужно менять параметр page на 1 и подставлять новый фильтр

Comment: `location.href = '...';`

Comment: Тут содержится два вoпроса (как заменить query-параметр; как выполнить программный редирект) - на какой из них ты хочешь получить ответ? Вoпрос должен быть сфокусирован только на одной проблеме, а тут даже проблемы не видно (ни попыток решения, ни уточнения возникших трудностей). Отредактируй, пожалуйста, чтобы можно было дать конструктивный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идёт об SPA, то для этого предназначено history api, а именно методы `pushState` и `replaceState`.

Если MPA и надо просто перейти на другую страницу, то можно сделать вообще без скриптов, указав ссылку в `action` формы. Первую страницу можно положить в скрытый input или вообще заранее включить в адрес.

А ещё страницу можно менять присваиванием `location.href`, но в описанной задаче я не вижу причин так поступать.